# Design: Java and returning self-reference in setter methods

Tags: java

For classes that have a long list of setters that are used frequently, I found this way very useful (although I have recently read about the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) in *Effective Java* that is kinda the same).

Basically, all setter methods return the object itself so then you can use code like this:

```
myClass
    .setInt(1)
    .setString("test")
    .setBoolean(true);
```

Setters simply return this in the end:

```
public MyClass setInt(int anInt) {
    // [snip]
    return this;
}
```

What is your opinion? What are the pros and cons? Does this have any impact on performance?

Also referred to as the [named parameter idiom](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html) in c++.

Comment: As in Joshua Bloch's book, Effective Java (2nd edition), one of the pros with the Builder Pattern, is you can more easily reason about the state of an object since once it has been created, it can't be mutated. It also gives a more fluent api to the clients of the class, especially when there is a lot of parameters to the class, many of which are optional.

Comment: Looks like this is known as the Named Parameter idiom in C++. I am generally in favor of it over traditional constructors with many parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752762/is-it-good-to-have-all-the-setter-functions-return-a-reference-to-the-object-in/  and  http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@pek
Chained invocation is one of proposals for Java 7. It says that if a method return type is void, it should implicitly return **this**. If you're interested in this topic, there is a bunch of links and a simple example on [Alex Miller's Java 7 page](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7#chained).

Comment: I find this idiom can be a nice idea (even though I wouldn't use it myself), but why extend the language if it can be done by explicitly declaring the return type of the setters to be non void? I do not like the idea of ad-hoc extensions to a language to support specific idioms.

Comment: I agree with @Giorgio. This is "magic" behaviour, and all magic is bad. It's magic in the sense that you cannot check the source to find out what it returns, you have to _know_ that void returns a self reference... I'd rather they introduced a new return type for this... call it 'self' instead of 'void'. Or something.

Comment: @Tor Valamo: I agree with you. In addition to this, I think that a programming language should provide **concepts** not **idioms**. If one really wants to use many idioms, one should use an extensible language like Lisp, but one cannot expect that a language is continuously extended to support all possible idioms: there are so many of them that a language can easily become (needlessly) complex.

Comment: The reason to build it into the language is that it can get painful when you want a hierarchy of chainable objects that return the most derived type.  Currently, you have to have `<Self>` generics to allow subclasses to change the return type so calling methods don't lose scope of the object they are calling.  Building into the jvm removes this ugliness.  Plus, instead of a return statement, it can just push a reference to this on the stack as needed; an "on demand return" instead of an "always return" that can be hard to optimize out when you don't use it.

Answer (score 10):

This is called a [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), for reference.

Personally, I think it's a pretty neat idea, but a matter of taste really. I think [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jquery) works this way.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it myself, because to me it muddies what a particular method does, and the method-chaining is of limited use to me over doing it longhand. It isn't going to send me into a quivering ball of rage and psychosis, though, which is always a good thing. :')

I wouldn't be concerned about performance; just ask Knuth.

Comment: Sometimes I see these monster sized constructors and the thing that comes to mind is how much easier the code would be easier to follow if they did some parameter chaining. I rather like the improved readability. Of course if it were all done on separate lines via vanilla setters that wouldn't be so terrible either.

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be in poor style when used in setters. Immutable classes are usually a better fit for chaining, such as:

```
aWithB = myObject.withA(someA).withB(someB);
```

where `myObject` is of this class:

```
class MyClass {
    withA(TypeA a) {
         this.a.equals(a) ? this : new MyClass(this, a);
    }

    private MyClass(MyClass copy, TypeA a) {
        this(copy);
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

The builder pattern is also useful, since it allows the final object to be immutable while preventing the intermediate instances you would normally have to create when using this technique.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense for builders, where all you are going to do is set a load of stuff, create the real object and throw the builder away. For builders, you might as well get rid of the "set" part of the method name. Similarly, immutable types don't really need the "get".

```
Something thing = new SomethingBuilder()
    .aProperty(wotsit)
    .anotherProperty(somethingElse)
    .create();
```

A useful trick (if you don't mind a ~2K runtime overhead per class) is to use the double brace idiom:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My frame") {{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocation(frameTopLeft);
    add(createContents());
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}};
```

Comment: That's not an "idiom". It's a horrible abuse of anonymous classes that doesn't become acceptable just because you give it a pretty name.

Comment: It's an idiom. It makes code less cluttered. It'll do for me until I'm using a language that can express it more clearly.

Comment: +1: two good points. why downvote? he's listed the caveat of runtime overhead.

Comment: -1: this obscure technique is not widely known and difficult to spot in maintenance.  Moreover when compared to a builder class, it has the drawback of introducing a distinct class at every single call site, rather than a single builder class for everybody.

Comment: Using inner classes when you don't need them will emit extra files per usage, and fill your PermGen memory.

The only way I would ever consider this strategy is if it was done in a very large class where you might get a lazy-load benefit from pulling functionality out into new class files.  Otherwise, you're paying runtime memory and excess compiled code size / class loading time.

Comment: @Ajax As I say about 2K. If you did it 500 times and had 1000 simultaneous users, that would be 1 GB. That's a total of a few pounds worth. How much is your time worth?

Comment: You forgot an important element in your equation: time.  ?GB per X users * Y sloppy classes * Z hours of operation = leaky, sinking ship.

It doesn't bother me if you don't care enough to write performant code; I like being able to charge a premium to slash and burn sloppy code.

Answer (score 0):

This idea is seen a lot in c++, it allows operations to be cascaded...

for example

```
std::cout << "this" << "is" << "cascading"
```

is where the stream method << returns an instance of itself (*this).

see this: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0180__Class/Cascadingmemberfunctioncallswiththethispointer.htm

Answer (score 0):

I use to be a fan of the Java (and worse C#) practice of making getters and setters (get set properties) throughout an object.  This use to be what I considered object oriented, but really this leads us just to exposing the guts and implementation of the object and not really taking advantage of encapsulation.  There are times you can't get away from this (OR/M comes to mind), but in general the object should be set up and then perform its function.  My dream objects tend to have one or two constructors, and maybe a half dozen functions that do work.

The reason for this is that once I started developing API's there is a real need to keep things simple.  You really only want to add as much complexity as is required to get the job done, and getters and setters, while simple in themselves, add complexity in heaps when added in mass.  What happens when I load setters i na different order?  Anythign different? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

@Dan again, for more complex situations (immutability comes in mind) the Builder Pattern is a great solution.

Also, I agree with you mostly in getters. I believe what you are saying is to mostly follow the "[Tell don't ask](http://www.pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask)" paradigm and I greatly agree. But that is oriented mostly at getters.

Lastly, all of the above are for classes that have a great deal of attributes. I don't see a reason for any if you only have less than, say, 7.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this a lot when working with the Apache POI excel library; I ended up writing helper methods that chained so I could apply formatting, data types, internal cell data, formulas, and cell positioning.

For stuff with lots of little tiny flyweight elements that need to have finicky little tweaks applied it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

How To Use

```
/**
 *
 * @author sanjay
 */
public class NewClass {
private int left ;
private int top;
public void set(int x,int y)
    {
    left=x;
    top=y;
}
public NewClass UP(int x)
    {
    top+=x;
    return this;
}
public NewClass DOWN(int x)
    {
    top-=x;
    return this;
}
public NewClass RIGHT(int x)
    {
    left+=x;
    return this;
}
public NewClass LEFT(int x)
    {
    left-=x;
    return this;
}
public void Display()
    {
    System.out.println("TOP:"+top);
    System.out.println("\nLEFT\n:"+left);
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    NewClass test = new NewClass();
    test.set(0,0);
    test.Display();
    test.UP(20).UP(45).DOWN(12).RIGHT(32).LEFT(20);
     test.Display();
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address the OP's original questions.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with @Bernard that method chaining like this muddles the purpose of the setters. Instead I would suggest that if you are always creating chains of setters like this that you create a custom Constructor for your class so instead of

```
    MyClass
    .setInt(1)
    .setString("test")
    .setBoolean(true)
  ;
```

You do

```
new MyClass(1,"test",true);
```

This makes it more readable and you can use this to make your class immutable if you chose to.

Comment: Actually, this makes it much, MUCH less readable if you have a large number of setters and there's a lot of variation in which ones you need to call. Trying to handle that with overloaded constructors will be a nightmare, trust me.

Comment: I disagree. Constructors should only have parameters for what is REQUIRED at the time of creation. Constructors for convenience are to make up for lack of a proper construct to handle the same semantics.

Comment: Polluting constructors is a bad idea, unless you have, say two or three parameters, tops.

Send anything final to constructors, and use setters for the mutable fields.